# Unix-portable way to get script's absolute path in zsh?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, filenames, symlink, portability

What is a portable<sup>1</sup> way for a (zsh) script to determine its absolute path?

On Linux I use something like

```
mypath=$(readlink -f $0)
```

...but this is not portable.  (E.g., `readlink` on darwin does not recognize the `-f` flag, nor has any equivalent.)  (Also, using `readlink` for this is, admittedly, a pretty obscure-looking hack.)

What's a more portable way?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Portable across OSs in the Unix family, that is.</sup>

Comment: See also [Will $0 always include the path to the script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119929/22565)

Comment: See also [Which macOS version introduced "readlink -f"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464136/which-macos-version-introduced-readlink-f), "-f" option for `readlink` appears to have been introduced in macOS Monterey 12.3 (March 2022).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With `zsh`, it's just:

```
mypath=$0:A
```

Or

```
mypath=$0:P
```

In newer versions (see [the manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) for the details on how they differ).

Now for other shells, though `realpath()` and `readlink()` are standard functions (the latter being a system call), `realpath` and `readlink` are not standard command, though some systems have one or the other or both with various behaviour and feature set.

As often, for portability, you may want to resort to `perl`:

```
abs_path() {
  perl -MCwd -le '
    for (@ARGV) {
      if ($p = Cwd::abs_path $_) {
        print $p;
      } else {
        warn "abs_path: $_: $!\n";
        $ret = 1;
      }
    }
    exit $ret' "$@"
}
```

That would behave more like GNU's `readlink -f` than `realpath()` (GNU `readlink -e`) in that it will not complain if the file doesn't exist as long as its dirname does.

Comment: Note: this does not work for your `.zshrc`: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901210/bash-source0-equivalent-in-zsh) instead.

Comment: Explanation for `:A` from `man zshall`: Turn a file name into an absolute path:  prepends the current directory, if necessary; remove `.' path segments;  and remove `..' path segments and the segments that immediately precede them.

Answer (score 71):

In zsh you can do the following:

```
mypath=${0:a}
```

Or, to get the directory in which the script resides:

```
mydir=${0:a:h}
```

See [the Zsh documentation on history expansion modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers), visible locally in `man zshexpn` or with `info -f zsh -n Modifiers` if the Info documentation is installed.

Comment: Sweet!  I've been looking for somethink like this for ages and read the whole bunch of the zsh manpages searching for it, but it would never have occurred to me to look under 'History expansion'.

Comment: The equivalent of GNU's `readlink -f` would rather be `$0:A`.

Comment: `:A`: 
Turn a file name into an absolute path as the `:a` modifier does, and _then_ pass the result through the `realpath(3)` library function to resolve symbolic links.  doc via [`info -f zsh -n Modifiers`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers)

Comment: Is the OP @kjo, asking for a "portable way to do [something], that only works in zsh"? Or is that how it is being answered? The above isn't portable to any other shell, besides, I am assuming, zsh (not a fan, don't know). Maybe a portable way of determining abspath in zsh AND other shells would be a better use of time and answer for future look ups.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. Another cool tip for anyone who is reading, if you want to get the parent directory of the directory in which the script resides, you can do `${0:a:h:h}`. Each additional `:h` you add will go up one additional directory.

Comment: This gives an incorrect result when the script is being run as `./script` and uses `cd` to change the directory before expanding `${0:a:h}`: https://pastebin.com/3xHsMGYB

Comment: this is the first thing that's bubbled to my attention where Bash has a shortcoming which Zsh lacks. rad !

Answer (score 18):

I've been using this for several years now:

```
# The absolute, canonical ( no ".." ) path to this script
canonical=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && printf '%s\n' "$(pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$0")")
```

Comment: i like it! so far, that's pretty portable.  works on Solaris, OmniOS, Linux, Mac, and even Cygwin on Windows 2008.

Comment: Where it's not equivalent to GNU's `readlink -f` is when the script itself is a symlink.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 with `zsh`, if I execute this either directly or in the subshell (as suggested) while in my home dir (`/home/ville`), it prints out `/home/ville/zsh`.

Answer (score 11):

This syntax should be portable to any Bourne shell style interpreter (tested with `bash`, `ksh88`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `dash` and `busybox sh`):

```
mypath=$(exec 2>/dev/null;cd -- $(dirname "$0"); unset PWD; /usr/bin/pwd || /bin/pwd || pwd)
echo mypath=$mypath
```

This version adds compatibility to the legacy AT&T Bourne shell (non POSIX):

```
mypath=`dirname "$0"`
mypath=`exec 2>/dev/null;(cd -- "$mypath") && cd -- "$mypath"|| cd "$mypath"; unset PWD; /usr/bin/pwd || /bin/pwd || pwd`
echo mypath=$mypath
```

Comment: thanks. though, I think unsetting `$PWD` might be overkill - you can just set it to absolute current like `cd -P .`. I doubt that would work in bourneshell - but it should work in all of the ones you tested for the first. does for me anyway.

Comment: @moose What OS are you running ?

Comment: who is moose? what?

Comment: @mikeserv moose is a passerby who posted a comment about some issue with `zsh` and `dirname` but quickly withdraw hir/her comment ...

Comment: Your Bourne Shell script will not work with a Bourne Shell as the Bourne Shell does not use getopt() for cd(1).

Comment: @schily Can you elaborate a little further? Did you test my script under a legacy bourne shell and see it failing?

Comment: The Bourne Shell ignores all superfluous arguments and tries to chdir() to the first argument (which is `--` in your example). If you like to check, get the portable Bourne Shell from http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/ and check the binary `osh` that has the original SVr4 feature set. The binary `sh`or `bosh`is a newer maintained variant.

Comment: @schily I'm aware of that. Look to my script logic closer, if the shell doesn't handle `--`, it falls back to legacy usage.

Comment: OK, after scrolling to the side I see this. BTW: The Bourne Shell does not support pwd -L/-P, but since 1989 it always returns the real path name as it always checks for symlinks.

Comment: On zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0) on macOS 13.2 this solution only returns the directory containing the shell script, not the file name of the shell script

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you really meant the absolute path, i.e. a path from the root directory:

```
case $0 in
  /*) mypath=$0;;
  *) mypath=$PWD/$0;;
esac
```

This works in any Bourne-style shell, by the way.

If you meant a path with all symbolic links resolved, that's a different matter. `readlink -f` works on Linux (excluding some stripped-down BusyBox systems), FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD and Cygwin, but not on OS/X, AIX, HP/UX or Solaris. If you have `readlink`, you can call it in a loop:

```
realpath () {
  [ -e "$1" ] || return
  case $1 in
    /*) :;;
    *) set "$PWD/$1";;
  esac
  while [ -L "$1" ]; do
    set "${1%/*}" "$(readlink "$1")"
    case $2 in
      /*) set "$2";;
      *) if [ -z "$1" ]; then set "/$2"; else set "$(cd "$1" && pwd -P)/$2"; fi;;
    esac
  done
  case $1 in
    */.|*/..) set "$(cd "$1" && pwd -P)";;
    */./*|*/../*) set "$(cd "${1%/*}" && pwd -P)/${1##*/}"
  esac
  realpath=$1
}
```

If you don't have `readlink`, you can approximate it with `ls -n`, but this only works if `ls` doesn't mangle any non-printable character in the file name.

```
poor_mans_readlink () {
  if [ -L "$1" ]; then
    set -- "$1" "$(LC_ALL=C command ls -n -- "$2"; echo z)"
    set -- "${2%??}"
    set -- "${2#*"$1 -> "}"
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$1"
}
```

(The extra `z` is in case the link target ends in a newline, which command substitution would otherwise eat up. The `realpath` function doesn't handle that case for directory names, by the way.)

Comment: Do you know of any `ls` implementation that _mangles non-printable characters_ when the output doesn't go to a terminal.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `touch Stéphane; LC_ALL=C busybox ls Stéphane | cat` → `St??phane` (that's if the name is in UTF-8, latin1 gives you a single `?`). I think I've seen that on older commercial Unices too.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've fixed several bugs but not tested extensively. Let me know if it still fails in some cases (other than lack of execution permissions in some directories, I'm not going to deal with that edge case).

Comment: @Gilles - what `busybox` is this? according to [git](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/log/coreutils/ls.c?h=1_22_stable) `busybox ls` hasn't had a code change since 2011. My `busybox ls` - circa 2013 - does not do this thing. This [one](http://www.busybox.net/live_bbox/.config) - circa 2012 - [does](http://bellard.org/jslinux/). [This](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/7993) might explain why. Have you built your `busybox` with Unicode support - to include wchar support? You might want to give it a go, else to check the build options in the `mkinitcpio` `busybox` package.

Comment: Gilles - I believe I initially misjudged this answer - or at least a part of it. While I firmly believe your *mangling filenames* mantra to be utter fallacy, definitely your *poor_mans_readlink* is very well done. If you will do me the kindness of making an edit - any edit will do - and pinging me afterward, I should like to reverse my vote on this.

Answer (score 3):

Provided you have execute permissions on the current directory - or on the directory from which you executed your shell script - if you want an absolute path to a directory all you need is `cd`.

[Step 10 of `cd`'s spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html)

> If the `-P` option is in effect, the `$PWD` environment variable shall be set to the string that would be output by `pwd -P`. If there is insufficient permission on the new directory, or on any parent of that directory, to determine the current working directory, the value of the `$PWD` environment variable is unspecified.

[And on `pwd -P`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html)

> The pathname written to standard output shall not contain any components that refer to files of type symbolic link. If there are multiple pathnames that the `pwd` utility could write to standard output, one beginning with a single /slash character and one or more beginning with two /slash characters, then it shall write the pathname beginning with a single /slash character. The pathname shall not contain any unnecessary /slash characters after the leading one or two /slash characters.

It's because `cd -P` has to set the current working directory to what `pwd -P` should otherwise print *and* that `cd -` has to print the `$OLDPWD` that the following works:

```
mkdir ./dir
ln -s ./dir ./ln
cd ./ln ; cd . ; cd -
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/home/mikeserv/test/ln
```

wait for it...

```
cd -P . ; cd . ; cd -
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/home/mikeserv/test/dir
```

And when I print with `cd -` I'm printing `$OLDPWD`. `cd` sets `$PWD` as soon as I `cd -P .` `$PWD` is now an absolute path to `/` - so I don't need any other variables. And actually, I shouldn't even need the trailing `.` but there is a specified behavior of resetting `$PWD` to `$HOME` in an interactive shell when  `cd` is unadorned. So it's just a good habit to develop.

So just doing the above on the path in `${0%/*}` should be more than enough to verify `$0`'s path, but in the case that `$0` is itself a soft-link, you probably cannot change directory into it, unfortunately.

Here is a function that will handle that:

```
zpath() { cd -P . || return
    _out() { printf "%s$_zdlm\n" "$PWD/${1##*/}"; }
    _cd()  { cd -P "$1" ; } >/dev/null 2>&1
    while [ $# -gt 0 ] && _cd .
    do  if     _cd "$1" 
        then   _out
        elif ! [ -L "$1" ] && [ -e "$1" ] 
        then   _cd "${1%/*}"; _out "$1"
        elif   [ -L "$1" ]
        then   ( while set -- "${1%?/}"; _cd "${1%/*}"; [ -L "${1##*/}" ]
                 do    set " $1" "$(_cd -; ls -nd -- "$1"; echo /)"
                       set -- "${2#*"$1" -> }"
                 done; _out "$1" 
    );  else   ( PS4=ERR:\ NO_SUCH_PATH; set -x; : "$1" )
    fi; _cd -; shift; done
    unset -f _out _cd; unset -v _zdlm                                    
}
```

It strives to do as much as it might in the current shell - without invoking a subshell - though there are subshells invoked for errors and soft links which do not point to directories. It depends on a POSIX-compatible shell and a POSIX-compatible `ls` as well as a clean `_function()` namespace. It will still function just fine without the latter, though it may overwrite then `unset` some current shell functions in that case. In general all of these dependencies should be pretty reliably available on a Unix machine.

Called with or without arguments the first thing it does is reset `$PWD` to its canonical value - it resolves any links therein to their targets as necessary. Called without arguments and that's about it; but called with them and it will resolve and canonicalize the path for each or else print a message to `stderr` why not.

Because it mostly operates in the current shell it should be able to handle an argument list of any length. It also looks for the `$_zdlm` variable *(which it also `unset`s when it is through)* and prints its C-escaped value immediately to the right of each of its arguments, each of which is always followed also by a single `\n`ewline character.

It does a lot of directory changing, but, other than setting it to its canonical value, it does not affect `$PWD`, though `$OLDPWD` cannot by any means be counted upon when it is through.

It tries to quit each of its arguments as soon as it might. It first tries to `cd` into `$1`. If it can it prints the argument's canonical path to `stdout`. If it cannot it checks that `$1` exists and is not a soft link. If true, it prints.

In this way it handles any file type argument which the shell has permissions to address unless `$1` is a symbolic link that does not point to a directory. In that case it calls `while` loop in a subshell.

It calls `ls` to read the link. The current directory must be changed to its initial value first in order to reliably handle any referent paths and so, in the command substitution subshell the function does:

```
cd -...ls...echo /
```

It strips from the left of `ls`'s output as little as it must to fully contain the link's name and the string `->`. While I at first tried to avoid do this with `shift` and `$IFS` it turns out this is the most reliable method as near as I can figure. This is the same thing Gilles's *poor_mans_readlink* does - and it is well done.

It will repeat this process in a loop until the filename returned from `ls` is definitely not a soft link. At that point it canonicalizes that path as before with `cd` then prints.

Example usage:

```
zpath \
    /tmp/script \   #symlink to $HOME/test/dir/script.sh
    ln \            #symlink to ./dir/
    ln/nl \         #symlink to ../..
    /dev/fd/0 \     #currently a here-document like : dash <<\HD
    /dev/fd/1 \     #(zlink) | dash
    file \          #regular file                                             
    doesntexist \   #doesnt exist
    /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.2-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 \
    /dev/./././././././null \
    . ..
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/home/mikeserv/test/dir/script.sh
/home/mikeserv/test/dir/
/home/mikeserv/test/
/tmp/zshtpKRVx (deleted)
/proc/17420/fd/pipe:[1782312]
/home/mikeserv/test/file
ERR: NO_SUCH_PATH: doesntexist
/dev/sdd
/dev/null
/home/mikeserv/test/
/home/mikeserv/
```

Or possibly...

```
ls
dir/  file  file?  folder/  link@  ln@  script*  script3@  script4@

zdlm=\\0 zpath * | cat -A
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/home/mikeserv/test/dir/^@$               
/home/mikeserv/test/file^@$
/home/mikeserv/test/file$
^@$
/home/mikeserv/test/folder/^@$
/home/mikeserv/test/file$               #'link' -> 'file\n'
^@$
/home/mikeserv/test/dir/^@$             #'ln' -> './dir'
/home/mikeserv/test/script^@$
/home/mikeserv/test/dir/script.sh^@$    #'script3' -> './dir/script.sh'
/home/mikeserv/test/dir/script.sh^@$    #'script4' -> '/tmp/script' -> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

what about a sympathetic one-liner when theres python available to prevent from redefining an algorithm?

```
function readlink { python -c "import os.path; print os.path.realpath('$1')"; }
```

same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305217