# Use find to find certain directory and delete all files in it except one directory

Tags: find

I'm having the following problem. I have a directory structure and want to delete everything that is within a directory named `Caches`. Everything should be delete except all directories named `Snapshots`. I can't figure out how to do this with **find** or any other command I know.

The reason I'm asking: On iOS every app has its own Caches directory. These sometimes don't get cleared properly, depending on the app. With the solution to this answer, one would be able to clear Caches on iOS, and therefore optimize the disk space, when the devices' drive is mounted on another computer, e.g. with FUSE (iExplorer).

This is what I have so far:

```
find . 2>/dev/null -type d -name "Caches" -maxdepth 3 -print
```

This returns something like:

```
./Library/Caches
```

When I do a `ls ./Library/Caches` I see all contents and the `Snapshots` directory, which I want to exclude because ultimately I want to `-delete` everything except this one.

---

I want something like this:

```
  Before:                            After:

  .                                  .
  ├── a                              ├── a
  │   ├── a                          │   ├── a
  │   └── Caches                     │   └── Caches
  │       ├── a                      │       └── a
  │       │   └── Snapshots          │           └── Snapshots
  │       │       └── a              │               └── a
  │       ├── b                      └── b
  │       │   └── a                      └── c
  │       └── c                  
  └── b
      ├── c
      └── Caches
          ├── a
          │   └── foo
          │       └── a
          └── b
              └── a
```

Comment: Well, one (dirty?) trick would be to use GNU tar with the `--remove-files` and `--exclude` options, and then delete the tar files (as bonus, if you accidentally removed a file you didn't intend to, and notice it before deleting the tar file, you can simply restore it from that archive).

Comment: What happens if you have a directory like `./Library/Caches/not_Snapshots/Caches/Snapshots/`? Do you want to delete that directory because it is inside `./Library/Caches/not_Snapshots/` or save it because it is a `Snapshots` directory?

Comment: @cristian-ciupitu Thank you for improving my question.

Comment: @Zett, [Stéphane Chazelas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/137131/4) deserves the whole credit. I should have probably mentioned him in the question too, not just in the changelog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -depth -print0 | perl -0lne '
  if ("$_/" =~ m{/Caches(/.*)}s && $1 !~ m{/Snapshots/}) {rmdir $_ or unlink $_}'
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-print0`, you can replace it with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`.

The idea is to print the list of files NUL-terminated (as 0 is the only byte that can't occur in a file path)  and use `perl`'s `-n` with `-0` option to run some code for each of those filenames (with `$_` set to the filename).

With `-depth`, files are printed before their parent directory. We remove only files or directories (assuming they are empty which is why it's important to process the list in `depth` order) if their path contains `/Caches/` not followed by `/Snapshosts/`.

Answer (score 7):

I am a little confused by wording of the question. If what you want to do is delete everything in the `./Library/Caches` directory apart from a single folder called `Snapshots`, there is no need to use `find`. In `bash`, shell globs are the simplest way:

```
shopt -s extglob  # probably already enabled
echo Library/Caches/!(Snapshots)
```

If this prints all the files/directories that you want to delete, then replace `echo` by `rm -f --`.

If there are multiple `Snapshots` directories at different levels of the directory tree below `./Library/Caches` that you want to preserve, then with GNU `find` you can do:

```
find Library/Caches ! -path '*Snapshots*'
```

This should print all files/directories excluding those that have `Snapshots`  in their path. It will include directories that contain (or whose children contain) `Snapshots` directories, however `find ... -delete` will not delete those and instead print an error that they are not empty. Once you are happy, add `-delete` to the end.

One caveat is that this will leave any *files* named `Snapshots` intact. If this is a problem, instead do:

```
find Library/Caches \( ! -path '*Snapshots*' -o -type f -name Snapshots \)
```

Again add `-delete` when happy.

Comment: Note that for the last one, adding `-delete` is not enough. You need `find Library/Caches \( ! -path '*Snapshots*' -o -type f -name Snapshots \) -delete`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a `find` sorcerer so I don't want to say that you can't do it with `find`, but I do know it can be done with a couple lines of `bash`.  Given that I understand your directory structure correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in Library/Caches/*; do
    if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then
         [[ "$i" =~ "Snapshots" ]] ||  echo "rm-ing  $i" # change to rm -rf "$i" to use
    fi
done
```

The `for` statement returns each item in `Library/Caches/`. The `if [[ -d "$i" ]]` statement checks that each item is a directory, and if it is, then it's name is checked to see if it contains "Snapshots", `[[ "$i" =~ "Snapshots" ]]`.  Because there isn't an operator to negate a regex match, like `!=~`, I used `||` to execute `rm` if the previous command is unsuccessful e.g. the directory name doesn't contain Snapshots.

This will run on any modern system using `bash`, but it must have `bash`. Also, you may need to play around with the directory structure, but that should do it for you.

Comment: `Snapshots` isn't a direct subdirectory of `Caches`, and there are multiple `Caches` directories. A recursive traversal is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ./Library/Caches
mv ./Snapshots ../    
sh -c 'rm -rf -- .[!.]* *' 
mv ../Snapshots ./
```

You don't need to set any persistent shell options. Just move the directory out, delete everything, then move it back in. I use the `.[!.]` glob above to handle any `.files` and put it within an `sh` statement because `bash` or `zsh` will likely not interpret the portable shell glob correctly. But if there aren't any `.files` you can use:

```
rm -rf -- *
```

..instead. Just don't do either in any directory in which you *don't* want everything deleted.

You can apply this same logic recursively - if there are multiple `./Caches/Snapshots` instances, for example. First make a hold directory on the same filesystem as `./Library/`:

```
mkdir -p hold ; hold=${PWD}/hold/Snapshots
```

Now `find` all `Snapshots` dirs, then save them elsewhere and delete the rest:

```
cd ./Library
find . -type d -name Snapshots -exec sh -c '
    [ "$0" != "${0%/Caches/Snapshots}" ] && {
    mv "$0" '"${hold}"' &&
    ( cd "${0%/*}" && rm -rf -- .[!.]* * ) && 
    mv '"${hold}"' "$0"
}' \{\} \;
```

Comment: `Snapshots` isn't a direct subdirectory of `Caches`.

Comment: @Gilles - that picture was not there yesterday. Do you often downvote working answers because they dont meet stipulations added after the fact?

Comment: Well, I think the downvote is fully justified in this case. It always makes my toenails roll up whenever I see `cd` in a shell script. This will cause nothing but trouble. Think of shell sessions, subshells, subshell A not knowing anything of subshell B and their parameters and vice versa---and so on. Avoid.

Comment: @syntaxerror - what does *A not knowing* mean? And what is wrong with `cd` in a script anyway? It should be used in scripts - it is designed for scripting. Look into the `$CDPATH` environment variable and the effects of `cd -P`.

Comment: Well it was *supposed* to mean that the first subshell doesn't know anything of the second, if there are two. And so things might give different results as you would expect because both subshells are *independent* of each other. But you might expect parameters to be "known" to both. (Heck, you even used `export`, so why doesn't that work?) However, you debug variables and get zero length and other nonsense. YMMV...but since I've avoided `cd` in scripts and specified paths directly instead, my scripts are less prone to errors. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cd_.2Ffoo.3B_bar

Comment: @syntaxerror - who used `export`? is this a joke? and yes, it is a good idea to use absolute paths when possible, but, when building information about paths, you have to go to the directory - it's what directories are for. And please, do not link the wooledge wiki - it is almost entirely composed of superstitions and ignorance.

Comment: Well, you're the first to complain about me linking it. Seriously. Though not all "tips" might be the creme de la creme, there *are* lots of neat tricks in there that have helped me many times. Still, I'm no "gregwoo fanboi" - but I wouldn't go as far as daring accuse him of "ignorance" either.

Comment: @syntaxerror - I personally despise the site. the occasional neat trick does not excuse blatant fallacy in my opinion. that site is rife with misinformation. I despise misinformation. I'm sorry to be so abrupt on the subject.

Comment: @syntaxerror have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152475/52934) for a better example of what might be done with `cd` in a script. And also, the page you linked, is among the better of the wooledge stuff, though many of those so-called *pitfalls* fail entirely to discuss the *whys* which is what I dislike the most.

Comment: Yes I agree it *IS* better than the great part of the other Bash PF articles. (I never link you to any pointless crap, mind you :)) And thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

First part: find directories named caches and do something with them

```
find . -name Caches -type d -exec … \;
```

Second part: traverse a cache directory, and remove everything, but keep `Snapshots` subdirectories and their content (as well as paths leading to them). Do a depth-first traversal, so that directories can be deleted once they become empty.

```
    find /path/to/Caches -depth -name Snapshots -type d -prune \
                             -o \( -type d -empty -o ! -type d \) -delete
```

Now combine them together.

```
find . -name Caches -type d -exec
    find {} -depth -name Snapshots -type d -prune \
                -o \( -type d -empty -o ! -type d \) -delete
```

Answer (score -1):

Why just not to find what you need by excluding what you want to keep?

Look for files rather than for directories:

`find . -type f | grep Cashes | grep -v Snapshot | xargs rm`

So you will find all files from current directories then you'll select only those files which are in directories `Cashes` then you exclude those files which are in directory `Snapshot` and then you remove the rest.

Above might leave empty directories but you could play with `find` options to get needed result.

Comment: That will also match `oldCaches` and `badSnapshot` etc. It will also break on the (unlikely) case of filenames with newlines and the (much likelier) case of filenames with spaces. It will also fail on cases where you have files whose name starts with a `-`.

Comment: should you have file names with spaces then a slight change in above will solve this issue as well
` find . -type ... | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | xargs -ifile rm file`

Comment: Yes, but that will break on, for example, files like `foo bar" baz`. If you want to make it really safe, you need `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm` or similar constructs. In any case, this does not help the main problem which is that you are not checking in the right places since `grep Caches` will match any file whose name or path contains `Caches` anywhere.

Comment: if to grep like this `grep '\/Caches\/'` and so on then your concern is also considered.