# Getting the full path name of a given directory

Tags: bash, directory

Suppose I'm in `/path/to/dir`.  Within this dir is another dir called `subdir`.

Is there a command I can issue which outputs the full path to `subdir`, no matter how it is identified? For example:

```
$ cmd subdir
/path/to/dir/subdir

$ cmd /path/to/dir/subdir
/path/to/dir/subdir
```

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76505/38906

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`coreutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)' `realpath` does the trick:

```
realpath subdir
```

and it works however the directory (or file) is specified:

```
realpath /blah/blah2/subdir
realpath ../blah2/subdir
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function somepath () {
  [ -z "$1" ] && { pwd; return; }
  (cd -P -- "$1" && pwd)
}
```

Simply creates a subshell (so that the `cd` doesn't affect your current shell) and prints the cwd. (Edited in a test for the "no parameter" case)